# Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm attempting to read a file in to the database that I have, but I'm receiving the above mentioned error. After checking to make sure that all the information was correct (i.e. nothing trying to be put into the database that doesn't have a column and such) I sill receive the error. Next I ran it my mysqlworkbench and it works fine. Now I'm not sure where to go to next I can't check the error any deeper considering its throwing on the ExecuteNonQuery. The file that I'm importing is 3000 lines. When I shorten the file it succeeded. I guess the first question is to ask is there some sort of max connection time and if so do I need to shorten my file or lengthen the time it can stay connected? Any advice would be great, thanks. Also I use the ,, to terminate the fields because some of the data can have a , in it.

```
public void sendQuery(string filePath, int month)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string monthName;

        monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month);
        monthName = monthName.ToLower();
        monthName = monthName.Substring(0, 3);

        try
        {
            command.CommandText = "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;" +
            "load data local infile 'C:/Users/mem-joshuad/Desktop/temp.txt' into table "+monthName+" fields terminated by ',,' lines terminated by '\r\n'";

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            ScreenNavigation n = new ScreenNavigation();
            n.homeScreen(ex.Message);
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Is there an Inner Exception being thrown when you get that error?

Comment: @LexWebb Not that I'm aware of. As you can see I handle the error which en turn displays it in a popup box and the only error I'm receiving is that there has been a fatal read.

Comment: if you debug your solution and set a breakpoint where you are handling the error, one of the properties of the error object will be inner exception, is it empty or does it contain another error? You can read more about innerExcpetions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I also edited that comment with the correct C# link instead of the Vb link.

Comment: Can't you do `ex.InnerException` to get the inner exception?

Comment: @LexWebb TIL: you can read exception properties (feeling shameful). Anyway inside all of the InnerExceptions the message is -  InnerException {"Unable to write data to the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."} System.Exception {System.IO.IOException}. I would assume that has to do with the server not responding due to some setting?

Comment: Looking at the error it appears that your initial assumption about a timeout could well be correct. You can set the timeout property of the SqlCommand higher to see if that helps. The property is called CommandTimeout.

Comment: @user3418145 are u using `microsoft application blocks` ?

Comment: @Webruster No i am not

Comment: Are you assigning a connection to the command, something like `command.Connection = conn`, anywhere in your code?

Comment: @LexWebb so far I'm not seeing any change other than whatever is causing the error is simply taking longer to happen, since the timeout is longer.

Comment: How long does it take to run in workbench? Have you set the timeout longer then how long it takes there?

Comment: @user3418145 Increase the Connection Timeout. By default it is 30 seconds. You can assign your own value to it.

Comment: @LexWebb it takes ~60 seconds I've changed it to that time at first it didn't work. Just did it again now it does. Don't you love programming and all it's mysteries? Thanks though for helping me debug the exception.

Comment: Haha no problem. I'd set the timeout extra long just to be safe, SQL databases can vary wildly in execution times when executing long queries.

Comment: @Webruster and thanks for your help too.

Comment: @user3418145    glad  you can figured it out !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do was lengthen the default time out. See comments for the process.